# UserPrincipal.current is return null in iis7,

Tags: c#, iis-7, ldap

the following is working fine in local machine(vs 2015) but when i released in iis7 user principal is getting null. can any one help me on this.

```
[ActionName("Login")]
    [HttpGet]
    [CacheFilter(TimeDuration = 100)]
    public async Task<List<Hashtable>> Login([FromUri]string id, string netPwd)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        bool response = false;

        // Build user id and password strings from KGP network credentials
        string uid = id;
        string password = netPwd;
        Hashtable hashChild = new Hashtable();

        List<Hashtable> list = new List<Hashtable>();

        // Define LDAP connection
        DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("LdapAccount", uid, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
        try
        {
            object connected = root.NativeObject;
            UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.Current;

            if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                string s = "tri";
            }
            string EmployeeId = userPrincipal.EmployeeId;

            domainName = System.Environment.UserDomainName;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Is the IIS running using the SYSTEM account?

Comment: my application in different server and iis in my local system so,i published application in my local system and added to iis.  i have enabled windows authentication.

Comment: it's running under "ApplicationPoolIdentity" Account

Answer (score 0):

finally i got the answer for this.. 
need to add

```
using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
        {
```

//code here

}

-- authentication is anonymous authentication, usually authentication based on your application.